# Cleaner way to store to replace a scalar hash value with an array ref?

Tags: perl, hash

I am building a hash where the keys, associated with scalars, are not necessarily unique.  The desired behavior to be that if the key is unique, the value is the scalar. If the key is not unique, I want the value to be an array reference of the scalars associated witht the key.  Since the hash is built up iteratively, I don't know if the key is unique ahead of time.  Right now, I am doing *something like* this:

```
if(!defined($hash{$key})){
   $hash{$key} = $val;
}
elseif(ref($hash{$key}) ne 'ARRAY'){
   my @a;
   push(@a, $hash{$key});
   push(@, $val);
   $hash{$key} = \@a;
}
else{
   push(@{$hash{$key}}, $val);
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: From a maintainability and simplicity standpoint, isn't it easier to assume that all keys are non-unique, and make every key an arrayref? Even if that arrayref contains one element? Translates to less `if ( ref $x eq 'ARRAY')` boilerplate all over the place.

Comment: @rjh this is a very fair point. I need to think about how this will play out in the larger picture for my particular case, but I agree it makes sense in general. It is simialr to how R handles things. This is part of a more complicated structure and duplicate keys are fairly uncommon. I am going to think about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**rjh** is right on the money.

I have written way too much code that does exactly what you describe--the hash value is an array ref unless it isn't.  Reams and reams of conditional type checking.  Then one day it hit me, "Why am I writing all this crap?  Just use an array ref everywhere, dummy" I said to myself.  Since that day bluebirds fly down from the trees to sing to me whenever I walk in the park.

```
push @{$hash{$key}}, $val;
```

That's all you have to do.  If the key does not exist, the array is autovivified.

If you don't like autoviv, and want to be explicit do:

```
$hash{$key} = [] unless exists $hash{$key};
push @{$hash{$key}}, $val;
```

Even this 'verbose' approach is much shorter.

Comment: Am I the only one to immediately imagine the scene from *Shrek* where the bluebird and Fiona sing and the bird explodes? :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that even an arrayref dereference would be autovivified. So I no longer have to do `@{ $hash{$key} ||= [] }` ... neat!

Comment: This is old question but I'm curious why use an arrayref at all?  Why not just hashref?

Comment: @vol7ron, if you want to have multiple values in your hash, you need to use a type of scalar that can store multiple values.  This leaves you with array refs, hash refs or some kind of serialization scheme to manage the multiples.  Depending on how you are using the multiple values, it may make sense to use a Hash of Hashes instead of a Hash of Arrays.  In this case, the OP was asking about a Hash of Scalars or Arrays.  I suggested using a consistent structure to save complexity.  This advice applies whatever elements you choose to compose your data structure.

Comment: @daotoad: that's right, I mean I've done HoA's, but HoH can be *abused* to serve all purposes. I mean it's really easy to create a `$hash->{$key}->{$index} = 'foo'` to serve the same structure of a multidimensional array, where index is equal to count of keys in `$hash->{$key}` or `0`. If order is important, simply add another dimension :)  I just find HoHs to be super flexible, but again, maybe I abuse it.

Comment: @voltron, if you need to be able to do quick membership lookups in the second tier structure, a HoH is the way to go.  But if you need to preserve the order of the members, a HoA is the way to go. What you suggest above only makes sense if you have a sparse array.  Otherwise you'd be better off to do `$hash->{key}[$index] = 'foo'`--it is faster and more memory efficient. `$hash->{key}{foo} = 1;` can be very useful, though.  This lets you quickly check to see if `foo` is a member of the collection `$hash->{key}`.

Comment: BTW, If you find yourself digging in to big complex structures a bunch, look into the Data::Diver module. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Diver

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!defined($hash{$key})){
    $hash{$key} = $val;
}
elsif (ref($hash{$key}) ne 'ARRAY') {
    $hash{$key} = [ $hash{$key}, $val ];
}
else{
   push(@{$hash{$key}}, $val);
}
```

Comment: You should really use `exists` in your first conditional -- there's a chance that `undef` might show up in `$hash{$key}`, in which case your final condition would clobber it.